# LINQ, Select only records where it reference exist in IQueryable<class> List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

I need to select all the records where FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE IN IQueryable using LINQ query. I am IQuerable list in ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES but getting error in second LINQ query

```
 public IList<ActiveUnitInstancesViewModel> GetActiveUnitInstances()
    {
        IList<ActiveUnitInstancesViewModel> _ActiveUnitInstances = null;

        using (var _uow = new FES_UOF())
        {
            IQueryable<UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity> ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES =                    
                    from UIO in _uow.UnitInstanceOccurrencesRepository.GetAll()
                    where UIO.STATUS != "WITHDRAWN" && UIO.STATUS != "INACTIVE"
                    group UIO by new { UIO.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE, UIO.OWNING_ORGANISATION } into grp
                    select new UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity {FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE = grp.Key.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE, OWNING_ORGANISATION = grp.Key.OWNING_ORGANISATION};


           var query = (from unitInstance in _uow.UnitInstancesRepository.GetAll().
                                 Where(x => ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Contains<UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity>( x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE ))
                         select new ActiveUnitInstancesViewModel
                         {
                             UnitInstances = unitInstance

                         }).
                         ToList();

        }
```

..

```
public class ActiveUnitInstancesViewModel
{
    public UnitInstancesEntity UnitInstances { get; set; }

    public UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity UnitInstanceOccurrences { get; set; }

    public VerifierEntity Verifiers { get; set; }

    public OrganisationUnitEntity OrganisationUnits { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

### SQL Script

```
WHERE UNIT_INSTANCES.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE IN
           (SELECT ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE
              FROM ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES);
```

### Error2:

[image]

### Exception

```
 System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233067
Message=Unable to cast the type  'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[[App.Entities.UnitInstanceOccurrences,  App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' to type  'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[App.Entities.UnitInstanceOccurre nces, App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
   at  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateAndAdjustCastTypes(TypeUsage toType, TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
   at  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetCastTargetType(TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType, Boolean preserveCastForDateTime)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateCastExpression(DbExpression source, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConvertTranslator.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression unary, DbExpression operand)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.UnaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.TranslateContains(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression sourceExpression, Expression valueExpression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.ContainsTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at App.EBSMiddleware.Engine.CurriculumServices.GetActiveUnitInstances() in  C:\MyDevelopment\EBSMiddlewareApplication\App.EBSMiddlewareServices\Services\Curriculum Mangement\ActiveUnitInstances.cs:line 80
   at ManagementConsole.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\MyDevelopment\EBSMiddlewareApplication\ManagementConsole\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 128
```

InnerException:

### This work from 1st Query

```
 IQueryable<UnitInstanceOccurrences> ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES =
                     (from UIO in _uow.UnitInstanceOccurrencesRepository.GetAll()
                     where UIO.STATUS != "WITHDRAWN" && UIO.STATUS != "INACTIVE"
                     group UIO by new { UIO.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE , UIO.OWNING_ORGANISATION } into grp
                     select new UnitInstanceOccurrences { FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE = grp.Key.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE, OWNING_ORGANISATION = grp.Key.OWNING_ORGANISATION })
                     .Distinct()
                     .OrderBy(o => o.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE);

            var d = ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE).ToList();

            var d2 = ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE).Contains("IH5MD019");
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Contains<UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity>` method you are using in your second query is not `String.Contains` or `IEnumerable<string>.Contains`. It is an `IEnumerable<UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity>.Contains`.

Your current logic is asking if the string `x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE` is contained in a collection of `UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity`, which is not possible.

Change your `Where` method in second query to:

```
x => ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES
    .Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE)
    .Contains(x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE)
```

Comment: I have change as you have mention above but I getting error;.... The entity or complex type 'App.DAL.DatabaseContext.FES.UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}

Comment: You cannot instantiate Entities by using `new` keyword. Entities should be constructed internally by EF. If you only want certain properties you need to say `new { FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE = grp.Key.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE, OWNING_ORGANISATION = grp.Key.OWNING_ORGANISATION }` as anonymous type. You should be able to use the result of it in your second query.

Comment: of course your would be able to say `new UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity`, but only outside an EF query. EF does this to ensure that entities are pulled from database as they exist in the database. Imagine you only pull 2 of 10 properties from database and then you called `SaveChanges` you would updating the other 8 columns with null values. This is just to ensure data integrity; and I love this restriction.

Comment: I am struggling contain work, I have updated my question under error2

Comment: @toxic, Could you display the whole exception?

Comment: I don't think the source of your problem is in the second query. It's in the first query. Remember that LINQ has deferred execution. First query does not execute until is needed in second query. Call `ToList()` on first query just to test where the source of the problem is located; you can remove it later.

Comment: I have update exception and also did ToList from IQueryable<UnitInstanceOccurrences> and that worked... updated my question

Comment: This is getting to nightmare ... if I have single column in list then Where(x => ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Contains(x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE)) works, but with 2 column and Where(x => ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Select(code=>code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE).Contains(x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE)) doesn't work